Transfer FSMO roles back to domain controller that the roles were seized from
Our domain controller failed, and we seized the FSMO roles on a new DC.
However, while creating the new DC, it was unable complete replication with another DC, due to issues falling to replicate with the failed DC.
Therefore the new DC did not complete replication.
After we seized the FSMO roles on the new DC, the failed DC was brought online and is running setup.
Can we seize the FSMO roles or transfer the roles to original failed DC now?

Can we seize the FSMO roles or transfer the roles to original failed DC now? You can transfer them. There shouldn't be a need to seize the roles.

the failed DC was brought online and is running setup. - What do you mean it's running "setup"?

Was it your only DC that failed? What is "the new DC" what is "another DC"? What roles does the "failed DC" think it still holds?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
